# How do I set the session cookie's HttpOnly setting to false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, httponly

In Ruby on Rails, how do I set the session cookie's httpOnly setting to false?

Comment: PSA: **don't do this in production**. The `httponly` flag is there for security. It might sound like it means "not https", but it actually means "not available to JavaScript". `httponly` is compatible with the `secure` flag, which means "only send over https connections". See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out.  In `/config/environment.rb` include this code:

```rb
  config.action_controller.session = {
    :httponly => false
  }
```

Comment: For what version of rails was this? I'm trying in rails 3, and get the following error: undefined method `session=' for ActionController::Base:Class

Comment: @Peter This was written before RoR 3 for version 2.3. It has not been tested with 3.

Comment: I made a workaround, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351871/session-cookie-httponly-false-rails-3-1/8371839#8371839

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 4, you need to edit `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store,
  key: '_socializus_session',
  httponly: false,
)
```

Comment: Reasonable question, CodeDave. You pass the key `:httponly` with the value `false`. (As per the other answers here - it's just that the location of the code to edit has changed from `environment.rb` to an initializer)

Answer (score 7):

This is how i did it with Rails 3:

```
Testapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_testapp_session', :domain => :all, :httponly => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails has it set by default to true.
I don't recommend to change it because it will set you cookies accessable for changing from JS like: `document.cookie`

In Rails 3+ you can change your cookies configuration from `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_my_application_session", httponly: false
```